# guessNum = int(input("guess the number between", minNum, "and",maxNum))でのエラー

Tags: python

勉強中に自分では解決できなかったので質問させていただきます。
最小値と最大値を入力し、ランダムで選ばれた数字を当てるコードを書いていますが、最後のラインでエラーが出てしまいます。

`print` を使うとエラーが出ないで表示されるのですが、`int(input)` を使うとエラーになります。この違いは何なのでしょうか？
教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import random 
minNum = int(input("what is the minimum number for the range")) 
maxNum = int(input("what is the max number for the range"))
prob = random.randrange(minNum + 1, maxNum + 1) 
guessNum = int(input("guess the number between", minNum, "and",maxNum))
```

Comment: `guessNum = int(input(f"guess the number between {minNum} and {maxNum}"))`

Comment: 「最後のラインでエラーが出てしまいます。」とのことですが、具体的なエラーメッセージを質問に追記してください。

Comment: TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 4とでてきます

Answer (score 2):

まず疑問に思ったらドキュメントをしっかり読むことをおすすめします
その上で 疑問が解決しない, あるいはキュメントが何処にあるか分からない などのとき質問するとよいのでは？
(その場合は, その旨記したほうがよいでしょう)

[組み込み関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html) より

> `input()`
> `input(prompt)`
>
> 引数 *prompt* が存在すれば、それが末尾の改行を除いて標準出力に書き出されます。次に、この関数は入力から 1 行を読み込み、文字列に変換して (末尾の改行を除いて) 返します。 EOF が読み込まれたとき、 [`EOFError`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#EOFError) が送出されます。

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=False)`
>
> *objects* を *sep* で区切りながらテキストストリーム *file* に表示し、最後に *end* を表示します。*sep* 、 *end* 、 *file* 、 *flush* を与える場合、キーワード引数として与える必要があります。

`print()` では複数のオブジェクトを指定でき
`input()` の場合 *prompt* ひとつ(最大でも一つ)しか指定できない

```py
>>> print(12, 345, 12+345)
12 345 357
>>> print(12, 345, 12+345, sep=', ', end='# カンマ区切り\n')
12, 345, 357# カンマ区切り
>>> print(f'12 + 345 = {12+345}')
12 + 345 = 357
>>>
>>> input('入力してください')
入力してください10
'10'
>>> input('入力してください', '最大10')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2
>>>
```